# From HUdson to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, backup, hudson

I need to pass from Hudson 3.3.3 to Jenkins 2.176.1. I have some jobs on Hudson that need to port in Jenkins. At the moment I tried "Thin Backup" plugin version 1.7.2, installed both in Hudson and Jenkins. Jobs are passed well and also build logs but job configuration is lost. The config.xml file is quiet diffferent from Hudson to jenkins.

I also tried to copy "jobs" dir from Hudson to Jenkins with same results.

What dou you suggest? Thanks.